# DynamoDB: how to query with multiple filter

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table and the structure looks like this:
[my table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4Da7.jpg)

Here correlationId is my hashKey.

I can perform simple query using hashKey:

```
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDB);
Pickup itemRetrieved = mapper.load(Pickup.class, key);
```

Now I want to query  on basis of fields i.e correlationId, partnerId to get transactionId.

How should I do that?

Comment: is partnerId your sort key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample code with multiple filter.

```
    List<Pickup> pickupList = null;

    DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);

    Pickup pickup = new Pickup();
    pickup.setCorrelationId(correlationId);

    Map<String, AttributeValue> attributeValues = new HashMap<>();
    attributeValues.put(":partnerId", new AttributeValue(partnerId));

    DynamoDBQueryExpression<Pickup> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Pickup>().withHashKeyValues(pickup)               
            .withFilterExpression("partnerId = :partnerId")
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(attributeValues);

    pickupList = dynamoDBMapper.query(Pickup.class, queryExpression);

    pickupList.stream().forEach(i -> System.out.println(i.toString()));
```

Comment: Can you please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61775937/dynamodb-query-with-filter-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Your partition key(correlation Id) is one keys on which you want to retrieve transactionid but it's missing partnerid.

Hence do these 3 steps 
Step 1 - build a global secondary index on partnerid
Step 2 -  filter on partition id
Step 3 - get transaction id

Comment: One more thing I want to clear.Is it mandatory to have a primary key for the query?Can we not just search on another field , like here correlation is my primary key, what if have to get the item on behalf of pickupid.

Comment: Here is the short summary in brief - any query on dynamodb has to be done using a partition key. Suppose your want to query on a non partition key then you need to first create a global econdary index on that field.                                                       Hence @neo, if you want to query on pickupid then create a global secondary index on pickupid.

Answer (score 0):

**Query Filtering**

DynamoDB’s Query function retrieves items using a primary key or an index key from a Local or Global Secondary Index. Each query can use Boolean comparison operators to control which items will be returned.

With today’s release, we are extending this model with support for query filtering on non-key attributes. You can now include a QueryFilter as part of a call to the Query function. The filter is applied after the key-based retrieval and before the results are returned to you. Filtering in this manner can reduce the amount of data returned to your application while also simplifying and streamlining your code.

The QueryFilter that you pass to the Query API must include one or more conditions. Each condition references an attribute name and includes one or more attribute values, along with a comparison operator. In addition to the usual Boolean comparison operators, you can also use CONTAINS, NOT_CONTAINS, and BEGINS_WITH for string matching, BETWEEN for range checking,  and IN to check for membership in a set.

In addition to the QueryFilter, you can also supply a ConditionalOperator. This logical operator (either AND or OR) is used to connect each of the elements in the QueryFilter.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `QueryFilter` does the filtering after the unfiltered read is performed: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.QueryFilter.html